# How to extract client number from filename

Tags: vb.net

Good Afternoon,

I am struggling with this (VB.Net) and need some assistance.

I have about 800 files in a directory, I want to get the filenames and extract the client number from.

An example of what the files look like in the directory are below:

`Client 11111 Proposal 47241 inputted.msg
 Client 22222 Proposal 88754 inputted.msg
 Interest Portfolio 5514720 inputted for Client 33333.msg
 Investment Proposal 0987654 inputted for Client 34343.msg
 Investment Proposal 1234567 inputted for Client 33333.msg
 Investment Proposal 7456781 inputted for Client 66666.msg`

When code is run it should get the below results:

`11111
 22222
 33333
 34343
 33333
 66666`

Below is the code I am using:

```
Dim path = txtWatchPath.Text
    Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.msg")

    Dim expr = New Regex("\bClient\b\s\d{5}")

    For Each file In files
        If expr.IsMatch(file) Then
            lsbxLog.Items.Add(file)
        End If
    Next
```

However the output from this code is displaying the below:

```
C:\Temp\Client 11111 Proposal 47241 inputted.msg
C:\Temp\Client 22222 Proposal 88754 inputted.msg
C:\Temp\Interest Portfolio 5514720 inputted for Client 33333.msg
C:\Temp\Investment Proposal 0987654 inputted for Client 34343.msg
C:\Temp\Investment Proposal 1234567 inputted for Client 33333.msg
C:\Temp\Investment Proposal 7456781 inputted for Client 66666.msg
```

Can someone help me please, I just need the client number from the filename.

Kind Regards,
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the client is always 5 in length:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim filenames As New List(Of String)
    filenames.Add("Client 11111 Proposal 47241 inputted.msg")
    filenames.Add("Client 22222 Proposal 88754 inputted.msg")
    filenames.Add("Interest Portfolio 5514720 inputted for Client 33333.msg")
    filenames.Add("Investment Proposal 0987654 inputted for Client 34343.msg")



    For Each fileName In filenames
        MessageBox.Show(GetClientName(fileName))
    Next fileName


End Sub

Private Function GetClientName(fileName As String) As String
    Dim leadingString = "Client "
    Dim startPos = fileName.IndexOf(leadingString) + leadingString.Length
    Dim parsedString = fileName.Substring(startPos, 5)

    Return parsedString


End Function
```